# how to evaluate $\arcsin(x)-\arccos(x)=\arccos(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse

**Question**

how to evaluate $\arcsin(x)-\arccos(x)=\arccos(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$

*Thoughts*

Do you cos on both sides to finally do quadratic equation to solve at the end of the problem? so i got $0=4x^2+4x-1+2\sqrt{3}$ on my last step but i dont know if this is the right approach

Answer (score 6):

Note that
$\arcsin(x)+\arccos(x)
=\pi/2
$.

Therefore
$\arcsin(x)-\arccos(x)
=\arccos(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})
$
becomes
$\arccos(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})
=\pi/2-2\arccos(x)
$
or
$\arccos(x)
=(\pi/2-\arccos(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}))/2
$.

You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: :D Best approach yet IMO

Answer (score 3):

You can't take the cosine of both sides, at least not the way you probably did.  You must do it as follows:

$$\cos(\arcsin(x)-\arccos(x))=\frac{\sqrt3}2$$

And then use sum of angles identity:

$$\cos(\arcsin(x))\cos(\arccos(x))+\sin(\arcsin(x))\sin(\arccos(x))\\=x\cos(\arcsin(x))+x\sin(\arccos(x))$$

And use pythagorean theorems (let's assume all positive)

$$=x\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\arcsin(x))}+x\sqrt{1-\cos^2(\arccos(x))}\\=2x\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 3):

From the unit circle, $\displaystyle \arccos\frac{\sqrt3}2 = \frac\pi6$.

A known property relating inverse sine and inverse cosine is $\arcsin x + \arccos x = \dfrac\pi2$.  Therefore:

\begin{align*}
  \arcsin x - \arccos x &= \arccos \frac{\sqrt3}2\\[0.3cm]
    \frac\pi2 - \arccos x - \arccos x &= \frac\pi6\\[0.3cm]
    -2\arccos x &= -\frac\pi3\\[0.3cm]
    \arccos x &= \frac\pi6
\end{align*}

Now take the cosine of both sides.

Comment: Same idea as mine, and you went all the way.

Comment: @martycohen, I could say likewise (except for the second part) as you posted yours less than 1 minute before mine.  And I dunno about all the way, I left a step at the end there XD

Answer (score 1):

I would just solve this using the unit circle. If you're working in degree mode, $\arccos(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) = 30^{\circ}$. So then, can you find a ratio $x$ such that $\arcsin(x) - \arccos(x) = 30^{\circ}$? If you look at a unit circle, you should see an immediate answer...